Find the node name of the JSON key from nested JSON
I have below JSON data:
{"GrossORNet":"Net","Term":"Monthly","Tier":{"All":{"1":{"Max":"100000","Min":"1","Rate":"15","StartDate":"2021-02-01","EndDate":"2021-02-01"}}}}

With below query:
SELECT json_extract('{"GrossORNet":"Net","Term":"Monthly","Tier":{"All":{"1":{"Max":"100000","Min":"1","Rate":"15","StartDate":"2021-02-01","EndDate":"2021-02-01"}}}}' , '$.Tier');

I can get the value of Tier, but I need the output of 'All' something like the first key name of the extracted JSON. Apart of using regex, is there any other option to get this?

Can you please add the desired output? And maybe few samples?

I have written in post I need output 'All'

One of possible tricks here is to cast json to map and work with it as with map:
SELECT
    map_keys(cast(json_extract(
            '{"GrossORNet":"Net","Term":"Monthly","Tier":{"All":{"1":{"Max":"100000","Min":"1","Rate":"15","StartDate":"2021-02-01","EndDate":"2021-02-01"}}}}'
        , '$.Tier'
    ) as map(varchar, json)))[1];

Output:
 _col0
-------
 All
(1 row)

Another option is to play with json_query() which has several functions including keyvalue:
SELECT
    JSON_QUERY(
            '{"GrossORNet":"Net","Term":"Monthly","Tier":{"All":{"1":{"Max":"100000","Min":"1","Rate":"15","StartDate":"2021-02-01","EndDate":"2021-02-01"}}}}'
        , 'lax $.Tier.keyvalue().name'
    );

Though this will not work (it seems there is a bug) for multiple properties in JSON object even if updated to work with arrays.

I need the output 'All', not 1

@Md.ParvezAlam 1) sorry it was not very clear, at least to me. IMO "output of All" can be understood in several ways 2) the solution is basically the same with shorter path. Will update it later.

P.S. Updated, please check
